# MVC 3 Windows Authentication Challenge on IIS7.5 Web Site (NOT app under default) Windows Server 2008 R2 VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication

your constructive suggestions and any help is required. 
I am creating a new WebSite in IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 for my corporate Intranet (not Application under existing Default Web Site!), and can't seem to get by authentication issue with Windows Authentication. I've went through all of the articles and postings here on StackOverflow as well as other sites, can't find working solution just yet.

Steps I followed to create and configure this new site in IIS7.5:

1. RDC to my VM, where I create the new Web Site on IIS 7.5. Open IIS Manager.
2. Did not change Default Web Site, which has bindings to no host name, All unassigned IP address, port 80. It is still there.
3. Right-click "Sites", "Add Web Site...", provided site name "sit", Application Pool: DefaultAppPool, physical path points to the app, which works on Dev Server (VS2010).
4. Click "Test Settings..." shows Authentication grid icon, Authorization yellow exclamation point: "cannot verify access to path".
5. Checking my physical path directory for Windows Security access (Windows Explorer), and can't find DefaultAppPool account to add to NT security access rights. Letting it be like this for now.
6. In "Binding" section of the "Add Web Site" form, used as mentioned above, I leave type: HTTP, IP Address: All Unassigned, Port: 80. In Host Name: I provide "sit", same as the site name above.
7. Click OK. Site is created, showing in the right pane, in "Sites" window. Click "Browse sit on *:80(http)" hyperlink on the rightmost vertical "Actions" panel. The browser IE8 starts, I get an error about DNS lookup not being able to find "sit", this is my Host Name as mentioned in step 5.
8. I go to my "hosts" file in my System32\drivers\etc directory, add entry: {MachineIP} sit, save.
9. Reload the browser, now it asks me for windows credentials. Provide my admin credentials on the box 3 times, and the browser gives me the following message:

"HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

**Logon Method Not yet determined**

**Logon User Not yet determined**

10.Checking my Authentication in the IIS7.5. It is decyphered from my web config correctly: Windwos Authentication Enabled, response type HTTP 401 Challenge. Anonymous Authentication disabled. Here is my web.config security settings:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <security>
    <authentication>
  <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />
  <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" useKernelMode="false" useAppPoolCredentials="true"> 
                <providers>
                    <clear />
                    <add value="NTLM" />
                    <add value="Negotiate" />
                </providers>
                <extendedProtection tokenChecking="Allow" />
            </windowsAuthentication>
        </authentication>
    </security>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
```

My Windows Athentication modules are both installed and referenced in IIS.

This is where I am unable to proceed any more and I need your help. I am missing something, but I can't figure out what it is. When  I go back to the site, and open "Basic Settings", I see that daunting yellow exclamaition point in "Authorization" on "Test Connection" popup, but I can't seem to figure out how to resolve it: I am logged in to my VM as Admin, I gave my physical location of the app full access, I tried using my admin account on the site as well as on the application pool, I've added Everybody account on the physical app directory with read-execute permissions, added IUSR, IIS_IUSRS,NETWROK SERVICE, etc. with permissions,  and still to no avail. I do not specifically understand:

1. Why would browser prompt me for my credentials, even if my browser settings say "Automatic logon with current user name and password", and my site host name is added to the "Local Intranet" list?
2. Why after I provide my valid credentials (3 times), I still get "Logon Method: Not yet determined" and "Logon User: Not yet determined"?

Here is my request, caught with Fiddler:

-[NTLM Type3: Authentication]------------------------------
Provider: NTLMSSP
Type: 3
OS Version: 6.1:7601
Flags:  0xa2888205
    Unicode supported in security buffer.
    Request server's authentication realm included in Type2 reply.
    NTLM authentication.
    Negotiate Always Sign.
    Negotiate NTLM2 Key.
    Target Information block provided for use in calculation of the NTLMv2 response.
    Supports 56-bit encryption.
    Supports 128-bit encryption.
lmresp_Offset: 160; lmresp_Length: 24; lmresp_Length2: 24
ntresp_Offset: 184; ntresp_Length: 24; ntresp_Length2: 24
Domain_Offset: 88; Domain_Length: 12; Domain_Length2: 12
User_Offset: 100; User_Length: 36; User_Length2: 36
Host_Offset: 136; Host_Length: 24; Host_Length2: 24
msg_len: 208
Domain: BLAHBLAH
User: sergey ivanchenkov
Host: LLLBBBAAA001
lm_resp: FA 6D 30 62 55 98 F6 70 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
nt_resp: F6 9F 3F D5 36 E5 7F 50 BF 4A 22 A4 E4 BA 5E F4 AB 29 31 04 8F FD D5 F3

Does anyone have any good suggestions to resolve this problem?
Sincerely grateful to the help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I had the same problem and this is what helped me:
https://serverfault.com/questions/485006/why-cant-i-log-in-to-a-windows-protected-iis-7-5-directory-on-the-server

phoebus wrote there:

> You are almost certainly running into the Windows loopback check that was introduced with IIS 5.1. This is a security feature to avoid certain types of reflection attacks against the system.
>
> Microsoft has a KB article describing workarounds. They basically boil down to modifying the registry to either disable the loopback check, or to allow certain hostnames (e.g. your local host name or site name) to back-connect.
>
> You can quickly disable the check via PowerShell:
>
> Below are Microsoft's official instructions. Note that although the below instructions indicate a reboot, I've found that IE usually picks up the change right away.
>
> Method 1: Specify host names (Preferred method if NTLM authentication is desired)
>
> 1. Set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1.
>
>    2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
>    3. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
>    4. Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
>    5. Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
>    6. Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
>    7. In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the sites that are on the local computer, and then click OK.
>    8. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.
>
> Method 2: Disable the loopback check (less-recommended method)
>
> 1. Set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1.
>
>    2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
>    3. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
>    4. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>    5. Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
>    6. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
>    7. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
>    8. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart your computer.
>
> Addendum:
>
> To set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1:
>
> 1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
>
>    2. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
>    3. Right-click Parameters, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>    4. Type DisableStrictNameChecking, and then press ENTER.
>    5. Right-click DisableStrictNameChecking, and then click Modify.
>    6. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
>    7. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart your computer.